# Using a variable in sed command is returnning sed: -e expression #1, char 7486: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline, sh

So in Jenkins I'm doing the following

```
 cert = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat cert.json")
 sh "sed -i '0,/content:.*/s//content: $cert/g' example.yaml"
```

so this is breaking the sed command when it replaces the `$cert` and puts `/g' example.yaml` on a new line which causes

> sed: -e expression #1, char 7486: unterminated `s' command

How can I fix this so that the `/g' example.yaml` is not on a new line

Comment: Can't you use the `r` command in sed to read the JSON from an external file? It would be much simpler than escaping the string for both sed and enclosing sh.

Comment: You probably have to append `.trim()` to the `sh` statement to get rid of the whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it by adding .trim() at the end

Comment: That is a comment. Please edit your answer to show the full script that solved your problem. Glad you solved your issue. Good luck.